# How to supress/ignore JSLINT error/warning for @ or at sign?

Tags: javascript, json, jslint

How to set a option for jslint to ignore the error or warning for at-sign(@)

```
object:  
        {   name: stackoverflow
            @href: http://stackoverflow/questions/ask }

console.log(object.name + "...name" + object.@href + "...href");
```

When complied I get this Linting error: E024: Unexpected '@'.

Note: @href is system generated;

Comment: I use grunt-jshint(not jslint), but there's a option, like {
 '-E024' : true
}, just try and see if it can help.

Comment: That's definitely not valid JavaScript syntax, which is why it's throwing that error.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I have displayed the JSON array value and trying to fetch(console.log) the href value using javascript snippet;

Comment: @Andrew: Dint work... :-( I got many errors after including that option to jslint;: [Bad option: '-E024']

Answer (score 1):

The JSON should look like this

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "@href": "http: //stackoverflow/questions/ask"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(object.name + "...name" + object["@href"] + "...href");
```

The code in your original example was not valid JS, so JSLint was correctly warning you of a legitimate problem with the code. The corrected version above is valid and JSLint should be happy with it above.

Aside: I assume the first few lines of your code snippet above is just meant to illustrate the structure of the object you're looking at?  The correct JS object literal would look something like this:

```
{
   name: "stackoverflow",
   "@href": "http://stackoverflow/questions/ask"
}
```

(or to make it valid JSON you'd need to put `name` in quotes as well)